# 500 internal server error on WordPress site after upgrading theme, WP ver, and plugins

Tags: wordpress

I just logged into my WP admin panel and updated my theme and plugins. I also upgraded to the newest version of WP. After performing all the updates, I tried accessing my site ([inlinecom.com](http://www.inlinecom.com/)) and my admin panel (inlinecom.com/wp-admin), but I get a 500 server error.

I've tried manually disabling my plugins and theme (by entering the cPanel file manager) and remaining the plugins and theme folder, but that doesn't do anything - still getting the 500 error.

I looked at my error log, and this might explain the 500 error:

```
[Sat Feb 21 11:06:21 2015] [alert] [client 75.119.255.235] /home6/phonesy1/public_html/inlinecom/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm working on this website for a company I work for, so I'm hoping I can get this resolved.

Thank you!

Comment: it's clearly .htaccess error, do you know how to find and edit that file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this problem, but I'm still not sure what exactly caused it. I renamed the .htcaccess file to .htcaccess_old then let WP generate a new .htcaccess file. Here's my old .htcaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAMEAddOutRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE te</IfModAddOut# END WordPress
DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Start CloudFlare:inlinecom.com rewrite. Do not Edit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^inlinecom.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# End CloudFlare rewrite.
```